# ngModel está mostrando os valores do input errado

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho um ngFor que percorre um array **produtosConfirmadosAnuncio**.

Dentro desse array possui o campo: valor_venda_atual, estou tentando fazer um *ngFor para percorrer esse array e mostrar um input pra cada produto, porém está mostrando os valores errados no input. Todos os inputs tem o mesmo valor do último elemento do array.

Tentei algo como:

```
<div *ngFor="let produto of produtosConfirmadosAnuncio; let i = index" class="col-xl-4">
    <div class="col-12 centralizaTexto" *ngFor="let variacao of produto.variacao; let j = index">
        <p class="card-text"><strong>Variação {{j+1}}</strong></p>
        <div class="row inline">
            <div *ngFor="let atributosvariacao of variacao.atributo" class="col-6">
                <p><strong>{{atributosvariacao.valor_atributo.item_atributo.item}}</strong></p>
                <p>{{atributosvariacao.valor_atributo.valor}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="col-xl-6">
        <input currencyMask [options]="{ prefix: 'R$ ', align: 'left', thousands: '.', allowNegative: false, allowZero: false, decimal: ',' }" name="valorb2w" required [(ngModel)]="produto.valor_venda_atual" type="text" class="form-control">
        <h6 *ngIf="produto.valor_venda_atual == null && submited" class="input-invalido animated shake">Valor obrigatório.</h6>
   </div>
```

Estou declarando o array dessa forma:

```
produtosConfirmadosAnuncio: any[] = []
```

Comment: Parece que o código está certo, o que me leva a crer que o problema é com a forma como o array `produtosConfirmadosAnuncio` é carregado. Você pode dar mais detalhes sobre isso?

Comment: @Nizer adicionei todo o fluxo aqui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri, quando um *ngFor é iterado sobre inputs, os names devem ser diferentes, eu coloquei no name="xxx{{indice}}" e funcionou